# componentDidUpdate update logged just after click in screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux

Im building a react native app and I faced a problem on `componentDidUpdate`.
When the app loads the `componentDidMount` call an api to check if the user are logged (using `firebaseService.auth().onAuthStateChanged` ), if it is, the app is redirected to main screen, otherwise to login screen. But the component just redirect to one of this screen when I click somewhere. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Follow my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, FlatList,ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import logo from '../../asserts/logo.png'
import { TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import ListCard from '../../components/User/ListCard';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import { restoreSession} from '../../store/actions/Section/actions';



class Load extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.restore();
        const { user, logged, error, loading } = this.props;
        console.log("restore");
        if(user && logged) this.props.navigation.navigate('User');
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { user, logged, error,loading } = this.props;
        console.log("aqui");
        if (!loading && !prevProps.error && error) Alert.alert('error', error);
        if (!loading && logged) this.props.navigation.navigate('User');
    }

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        animating: false,
        align: 'flex-start',
        alignsecond: false,
      };

      setTimeout(
        () =>
          this.setState({ align: 'flex-start' }, function() {
            this.setState({
              alignsecond: true,
            });
          }),
        100
      );
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            //flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: this.state.align,
            marginTop : 150,
          }}>
          <Image
           source={logo} 
            style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
          />
          {!this.state.alignsecond ? null : (
            <View style={{ margin: 10, justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center' }}>
            <Text
              style={{ color: '#6F1121', fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold' ,justifyContent:'center'}}>
              HomeShare
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{  fontSize: 15,justifyContent:'center' }}>
              Find a place to Share !
            </Text>
            <ActivityIndicator style={{  marginTop:20 }} size="large" color="gray" />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    containerCard:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        paddingTop:10 ,
        paddingLeft:20,
        paddingRight:20,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 222, 211, 0.25)',


      //  marginTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 44 : StatusBar.currentHeight, 

    },
    container:{

      flex:1,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 222, 211, 0.25)',
    }


});


const mapStateToProps = ({ section: { restoring, loading, user, error, logged } }) => ({
    restoring: restoring,
    loading: loading,
    user: user,
    error: error,
    logged: logged
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = {
        //login:loginUser,
        restore:restoreSession
  };
  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Load);
```

My Action:

```
export const restoreSession = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(sessionLoading());

  firebaseService.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
      if (user) {
        //console.log(user);
        firebaseService.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
         dispatch(sessionSuccess(idToken))


        }).catch(function(error) {
          dispatch(sessionError(e));
        });

        //dispatch(sessionSuccess(user));

      } else {
        dispatch(sessionLogout);
      }
  })

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would lose the logic for the componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate and just put the onAuthStateChange here in the componentDidMount so you can execute the navigate to the page.

Anyway, your problem is that the componentDidUpdate is executed when the page refreshes and that won't happen until you interact with it, and that is why it only analyzes the logged variable after you touch the screen. If you are thinking that the componentDidUpdate will execute every time you receive a new prop, that is wrong.

You should check this https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if componentDidUpdate doesnt update every time my props change(using redux), how can I can handle this action and only render my component when I get a response from an action called by props?

Comment: Well, first of all, I cannot see the code in your onAuthStateChange, since that is async, and you might actually not even be calling the redux. And second componentDidUpdate might trigger on UI changes.

Comment: I updated my code, I can understand the reason this doesn't work, since Im updating my state....

Comment: What I believe is happening in your code is that the DOM is not actually being modified with your logged prop so the render does not fire therefore the componentDidUpdate won't fire. Try to use the logged variable in the dom like a hidden variable or text and see if that works. Still, I am usually against this type of flow. I'd have the onAuth in the same logic and navigate from it, and not from a prop update in redux. (even if you want to update the session in the same step tho)

Comment: I changed my logic putting onAuthStateChange in componentDidUpdate, but I still have the same issue. Just redirect to User page when I click on screen componentDidMount(){
        firebaseService.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate(user ? 'User' : 'Login')
        })
      }

Comment: That would be the same, because the componentDidUpdate executed AFTER updating the DOM and render. If you add that login in the componentDidMount it should work.

Comment: After a lot of headache I discovered that problem was my debug. I disable it and worked. Thanks for your help.